# How to determine a primary decomposition of $(X^aY^b,(X+Y+Z)^c)$ in $k[X,Y,Z]$

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove that the primary decomposition of $(X^aY^b,(X+Y+Z)^c)$ in $k[X,Y,Z]$, for a,b,c positive integers, is $(X^a,(X+Y+Z)^c) \cap (Y^b,(X+Y+Z)^c)$. The equality of the ideal and the intersection is easy to see, but I am not succeeding in proving that the ideals $(X^a,(X+Y+Z)^c) $ and $ (Y^b,(X+Y+Z)^c)$ are primary, so I am not sure that I am on the right track. So the questions would be - is this a correct decomposition? How to see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** If $\phi:K[X,Y,Z]\to K[X,Y,Z]$ is given by $\phi(X)=X$, $\phi(Y)=Y$, and $\phi(Z)=Z-X-Y$, then $\phi$ is a $K$-automorphism, and the image by $\phi$ of your ideals are monomial.

Comment: I just tried writing it down, but I can't see what you mean. If you could elaborate...

Comment: $\phi((X^aY^b,(X+Y+Z)^c))=(X^aY^b,Z^c)$, and this is a monomial ideal whose primary decomposition is $(X^a,Z^c)\cap(Y^b,Z^c)$. Now go back with $\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: That is a great little trick! So much easier than trying to prove by hand.

Comment: I always wonder in these situations if I would have ever thought of that :)